# rsuite Popover component accessible via keyboard's tab key

Tags: reactjs, popover, whisper, rsuite

- I used [rsuite Popover](https://v3.rsuitejs.com/en/components/popover) to create popover with two buttons. When I
  get focus to the popover button using keyboard tab and clicked enter
  button, Popover dialog box successfully opened with two buttons.
- But when I click again tab button to go inside the popover, its not
  working, The tab focus go inside the next buttons that's are out of
  popover. When I click the tab button continuously, the tab button get
  focus to other buttons in the page and at the last the tab focus go
  inside the popover button.
- What actually happens: The control goes through all the buttons first
  and then at the end it comes to the popover contents if the popover
  is active.
- How can I achieve this? That the focus should come to popover
  contents immidiately after the button to which the popover belongs
  to?

Can anyone tell me how can I handle this? I am new to this.

```
    function tableElements(handleViewButton: {
    (rowData: Schedules): () => void;
    (arg0: SchedulesRow): React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLSpanElement> | undefined;
}) {
    const edit = {
        title: '',
        render: function Render(rowData: SchedulesRow) {
            const getRef = (element: HTMLButtonElement) =>
                editButtonsRef.current.splice(findButtonIndex(rowData.scheduleIdentifier, dataTable as any), 1, element);
            return (
                <div style={{
                    display: 'block', width: 80, paddingLeft: 5, paddingRight: 5
                }}>
                    <Whisper
                        trigger="click"
                        placement='bottom'
                        speaker={
                            <Popover>
                                <div className="button-wrapper">
                                    <button
                                        className={`icon-wrapper ${styles.editButton}`}
                                        aria-label={`Button1 ${rowData.scheduleIdentifier}`}
                                        onClick={() => handleViewButton(rowData)}
                                        ref={getRef}
                                        disabled={!schedulePermissions.edit?true:false}
                                        tabIndex={0}
                                    >
                                        <i className="fa fa-pencil pointer" aria-hidden/><span> Button1</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="button-wrapper">
                                    <button
                                        className={`icon-wrapper ${styles.editButton}`}
                                        aria-label={`Button2 ${rowData.scheduleIdentifier}`}
                                        onClick={() => {handleDeleteButton(rowData)}}
                                        ref={getRef}
                                        disabled={!schedulePermissions.delete?true:false}
                                        tabIndex={0}
                                    >
                                        <i className="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden/><span> Button2</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </Popover>
                        }
                    >
                        <Button appearance="subtle" className="gear-wrapper" tabIndex={0}>
                            <i className="fa fa-gear"></i>
                        </Button>
                    </Whisper>
                </div>
            );
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Popover does not support focus trapping for now.